# Connection could not be found

Tags: 16.04, connection

Recently, Whenever I try to connect to the wifi, I click on the network and I get a warning saying "connection activation failed: connection could not be found". I even reinstalled Ubuntu and i still get this warning.

Answer (score 6):

To try and check where your wifi issues may be, troubleshooting using these commands in a terminal (`Ctrl` + `Alt` + `T`) can be handy:

- Check status of connectivity: `nmcli networking connectivity`
- Check that wifi is properly activated: `nmcli radio wifi off ; nmcli radio wifi on`
- See wifi access-points: `nmcli device wifi rescan ; nmcli device wifi list`
- Try to connect to wifi: `nmcli device wifi connect "$WIFI_AP" password "$WIFI_PW"`

Each of these should give you a hint as to why they fail , if they do.

Further information can be found in `man nmcli`